# Is ran for time in CPU Scheduling the same as response time?

Tags: c, operating-system

So basically our code must be in this format

"process (process-name) arrived at time (T) and ran for (n) MS. it had a turn-around time of (M)"

The thing is I Don't know what "ran for MS" means. Is this the response time or waiting time or what is it? Clarification would be very much appreciated

Comment: It means that it executed code on the CPU for that many ms before being preempted or waiting.

Comment: It could mean milliseconds, but if that is the case, the question is incorrectly written.

Comment: Silly fun fact: 1 MS (one mega-second) is approximately 11.574 days.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.